# sql cinema reservation schema, get the proper data

Tags: php, mysql

This is my database schema, if a user checked a checkbox then each checkbox will be added in the seats_reserved.

I uploaded the old schema, THE LATEST SCHEMA has the screening_Id inside the reservation table as a foreign key. that's all.

[image: Cinema Reservation]

This is what the UI looks like, I am getting those checkbox by this code

```
   if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header("Location: login.php?error=not_login");
    exit();
    } else {
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                $temp_branch_id = $_POST['branch'];
                $temp_movie_id = $_POST['movie'];
                $temp_screening_id = $_POST['screening'];

            $seats = $mysqli->query("
SELECT seat.id
     , s.row
     , s.number
  FROM movies m
  JOIN screening n
    on m.id = n.movie_id 
  JOIN branches b
    on n.branch_id = b.id 
  JOIN seats s
    on b.id = s.branch_id 
 WHERE n.id = $temp_screening_id
") 
            or die($mysqli->error);

        } 
    }
?>

<div class="theatre">
   <h1>Please select a seat  </h1>
</div>  

 <form method="post" action="includes/seats_reservation.inc.php">
      <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="screening_id" value="<?= $temp_screening_id ?>">
         <?php 
            $i=1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($seats)) {
            ?>
             <input type="checkbox" name="seats_check[]" id="<?= $row['id']; ?>" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>/>
            <label for="<?= $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['row'].$row['number'] ?></label>
            <?php if ($i%10 == 0) { ?>
                  </div>
                  <div>
            <?php }
                    $i++;
                    }
            ?>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
      Submit
      </button>
   </form>
```

[image: UI]

What I want to accomplish is that I want to make the checkboxes disabled if they are already taken based on a screening ID, but whenever I am querying the data, this is what I get. I want to get all of the seats in the selected screening time their status if they're active or not.

I was just following this post but I cant seem to make it work. Is there something wrong with my schema?

http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/technical-articles/a-database-model-for-a-movie-theater-reservation-system

[image: What I get]

Comment: You should remove the `WHERE reserve.screening_id = 7` --  And in your `php`programming check the `if ($array['screening_id'] === 7)` Then set the checkbox to disabled

Comment: How are you handling unpaid reservations? Can someone reserve a seat for a period of time whilst they complete the payment process?

Comment: @Zak if I removed the screening, how will I get the chairs, assigned to that time? I tried removing it but instead I am getting every seats including the seats from other branches

Comment: It has an approval in the employee dashboard, if the customer paid thru bank then they will approve the reservation

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the php stuff for now, and instead focus on the sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query isn't far off. All you need to do is test for the existence of a reservation, and return that value as a column.

If a seat has a seat reservation, and the reservation is active, then the seat is unavailable, otherwise it's available for booking.

```
SELECT s.*, IF(r.id AND sr.id, 0, 1) AS available
FROM seats s
INNER JOIN branch b 
    ON b.id = s.branch_id 
    AND b.id = :branchId
INNER JOIN screening sc 
    ON b.id = sc.branch_id 
    AND sc.id = :screeningId
LEFT JOIN seat_reserved sr 
    ON s.id = sr.seat_id 
    AND sc.id = sr.screening_id
LEFT JOIN reservation r
    ON r.id = sr.reservation_id
    AND r.active = 1;
```

You will then need to set the parameter bindings for `:branchId` and `:screeningId`.

Comment: I literally copy pasted this but it says, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':branchId
INNER JOIN screening sc 
    ON b.id = sc.branch_id 
    AND sc.id ' at line 5

Comment: @IvanApungan - I'm glad it worked. Did you see that you needed to replace the parameter bindings?